# Print from card not showing on new SKR mini e3 v1.2 card

Tags: troubleshooting, skr-mini-e3, microsd

I am a newbie with a 3 months old Ender 3 Pro, my first one.  I purchased, installed and loaded a new SKR Mini E3 V1.2 mobo.  The LCD panel lit up as usual without problems.  I selected 'print from card' which showed the micro SD card had 2 files, FIRMWARE and test, as I recall.  Then I put the SD card into a micro-SD to SD card adapter, which I hoped to use, and plugged it into the card slot but it didn't work.  I fiddled with it a little, then removed the adapter and discarded it. I then removed the card and copied it onto my PC for safekeeping.  I also added 2 short, simple .gcode files to check out the printer.  I put it back into the printer and turned it on.  The panel came on listing several entries but Prepare, Control and Print from Card were missing. I opened and scrolled each item, even clicking on 'Initiate EEPROM' but without success.  I plugged and re-plugged the SD card, restarted the printer several times with no luck.  Put the SD card back into the PC and both original files plus the 2 .gcode files I added were still there. This exhausts my meager knowledge of things to do and I surely hope someone can help me out!

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE! Did you unmount the card before you pulled it from the printer?

Comment: Thank you Paulster2.  No, I don't think so--there is no entry I remember that says something like "unmount card'.  With the stock E3 board, there was an entry to the effect of "replace sd card', but not on the SDK board.  I am still trying to master 3D print terminology, which works to my great disadvantage and I apologize